# Shell file works when run manually but fails when run in CRON

Tags: java, cron, classpath, aix

I have a shell file (compile.sh) that compiles then runs a java program.  It works when I run it manually on an AIX server but gives me an error when I run it through CRON.

compile.sh :

```
/usr/java6/bin/javac  -classpath :.:/usr/jdk/commons-net-3.0.1.jar:/usr/jdk/classes12.jar:/usr/jdk/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar:/usr/jdk/jtds-1.2.5.jar:/usr/jdk/mail.jar:/usr/jdk/joda-time-1.6.2.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/mailapi.jar:/usr/jdk/pop3.jar:/usr/jdk/smtp.jar:/usr/jdk/dsn.jar:/usr/jdk/imap.jar -d . daily_transmission.java

java -classpath :.:/usr/jdk/commons-net-3.0.1.jar:/usr/jdk/classes12.jar:/usr/jdk/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar:/usr/jdk/jtds-1.2.5.jar:/urs/jdk/mail.jar:/usr/jdk/joda-time-1.6.2.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/mailapi.jar:/usr/jdk/pop3.jar:/usr/jdk/smtp.jar:/usr/jdk/dsn.jar:/usr/jdk/imap.jar daily_transmission
```

error:

```
/ttms/its/db/dropez/trans/compile_java.sh
javac: file not found: *.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: daily_transmission
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: daily_transmission
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
Could not find the main class: daily_transmission. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change directory before compiling and running :

```
cd /absolute/path/to/your/project

/usr/java6/bin/javac  -classpath :.:/usr/jdk/commons-net-3.0.1.jar:/usr/jdk/classes12.jar:/usr/jdk/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar:/usr/jdk/jtds-1.2.5.jar:/usr/jdk/mail.jar:/usr/jdk/joda-time-1.6.2.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/mailapi.jar:/usr/jdk/pop3.jar:/usr/jdk/smtp.jar:/usr/jdk/dsn.jar:/usr/jdk/imap.jar -d . daily_transmission.java

java -classpath :.:/usr/jdk/commons-net-3.0.1.jar:/usr/jdk/classes12.jar:/usr/jdk/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar:/usr/jdk/jtds-1.2.5.jar:/urs/jdk/mail.jar:/usr/jdk/joda-time-1.6.2.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/jdk/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/jdk/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/usr/jdk/mailapi.jar:/usr/jdk/pop3.jar:/usr/jdk/smtp.jar:/usr/jdk/dsn.jar:/usr/jdk/imap.jar daily_transmission
```

** **Update** **

In fact, `cron` executes every job from the user's home directory. Therefore, it is best to change your working directory from your shell script. Or even write your query as if you were sitting in your home directory (or root), by specifying absolute paths to every files and folders.